# Reinstall Ubuntu Server No GUI

Tags: command-line, server, reinstalling

I want to uninstall my Ubuntu server OS. And it's no problem if all data is lost. I want a clean reinstall (Delete all data, then reinstall)

Comment: Why ask here when the installation procedure is well documented? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server#1-overview

Answer (score 1):

Insert Ubuntu Server LiveUSB. Boot from it. Follow the prompts.

There is no "system restore" or "factory reset" feature in Ubuntu Server, as reinstalling is less complex and just as fast.

Comment: I've tried to boot from the USB, but it still goes to the existing OS and configuration and didn't ask for a prompt like settings, name, location layout

Comment: "*[I]t still goes to the existing OS*" 1) Ensure that you have a properly-made LiveUSB that is actually bootable. 2) When booting, enter your machine's BIOS settings and  select the correct boot device.

Comment: Thanks, Mate, it works